# Manipulate DOM on success event of jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In success event of  a jquery plug in I need to manipulate the DOM and create/make visible some new html controls...

HTML..

```
<input type="file" name="fileupload" id="fileupload" />

<%=Html.ActionLink("TestA", "TestA", "ControllerA", new { Id = Id})%> 

<%=Ajax.ActionLink("TestB","TestB","ControllerB", new { Id= Id})%>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    $('#fileupload').uploadify({
        'buttonText': 'Upload',
        'auto': true,
        'multi': false,
        'swf': '/Uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader': '/ControllerA/LinkMethod',
        'formData': { 'Id': Id},
        'debug': false,          
        'onUploadSuccess': function (file, data, response) {

         //Here I want to show two action links and disable/invisible the plugin.

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `show()` and `hide()` for the respective elements with the corresponding id value.

```
 'onUploadSuccess': function (file, data, response) {

        $('#MyIdForLink1').show();
        $('#MyIdForLink2').show();
        $('#pluginId').hide();

 }
```

Comment: Or in one-line: `$('#MyIdForLink1, #MyIdForLink2, #pluginId').toggle();`